# Embedded Binary

Tags: xcode, binary, codesign

error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.

Also, why does my profile keep getting replaced with a XC wildcard profile?

Comment: hi, please let me know how u fix this issue...

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. I followed this steps to solve.

1. go to my Build setting and changed all Code Signing Identify to iOS Distribution.
2. Compile m Project
3. XCode throws error message that Signing identity is wrong with an option to fix it. I clicked Fix it button.
4. It happened twice.
5. Now XCode change it back to IOS Developer.

Now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

For code sign issue please check if this works
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42244194/1084174

For auto profile creation, 
You must disable automatic management for all targets in your app.

[image]