# Not uploading a watch kit app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit

Ive made an iPhone app and started playing around with a watch kit app with it in the same project. However, I only want to upload the iPhone app now not the watch kit app. How do I only upload the watch kit app? I have this problem [Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906188/embedded-binary-is-not-signed-with-the-same-certificate-as-the-parent-app) but I don't want to upload my watch kit app. Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent deploying (disable) WatchKit App with iOS iPhone App in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426501/prevent-deploying-disable-watchkit-app-with-ios-iphone-app-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Removing watchOS Target**

> You should just remove the Watch Extension.

*Solution:*

Go to *Build Phases* in iOS target, which is located in your Project file, then from *Target Dependencies*, remove WatchKit Extension target.

Also in the same page, you should go to *Embed App Extensions* and remove the WatchKit extension.

Then, clean, build and run your project as usual. You should be done.

**Re-adding watchOS Target**

> The only step is to add the extension to *Target Dependencies*.

**NOTE:** However, if you are working with watchOS 1, after adding the extension to *Target Dependencies*, you should add it to the *Embed App Extensions* too. Just select the *.appex file containing WatchKit extension data there.

**Conclusion**

1- To remove watchOS Target, remove it from both *Target Dependencies* and *Embed App Extensions*.

2- To re-add watchOS Target,

A) In watchOS 2, add it to *Target Dependencies*.

B) In watchOS 1, also add the *.appex file to *Embed App Extensions* as well as adding the extension to *Target Dependencies*.