# Xcode 9 - Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app

Tags: xcode, code-signing

We have a project with an app main target and two extension targets: content extension and service extension. All of these have the exact same signing settings but I get this error when trying to create an archive in Xcode:

> error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the
>   parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings
>   match the parent app's.
>
> Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:  - (Ad Hoc Code Signed)      Parent
>   App Signing Certificate:      iPhone Developer: XXXX XXXX (XXXXXXXX)

Obviously this is a keychain signing certificate issue. I had many older, expired certificates installed before and it compiled. Then I deleted all expired ones and now the builds fail. But the required certificates are installed and set properly in the project settings.

Time wasted on the issue: 2 days. Thanks Apple!
Can anyone point in the right direction here?

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution here: [Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906188/embedded-binary-is-not-signed-with-the-same-certificate-as-the-parent-app#27908394)

...

> Make sure that your certificate is never ever set as Always Trust.
>   Access must be kept as Use System Default