# Notification Service Extension Signing Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, ios-app-signing

I want to upload iOS app to App store. For that i have selected distribution certificates for app target.I has `Notification Service Extension` & `Notification Content Extension` and i have set Automatically Manage Signing.

[image: Image 1]

I got this error `"Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's."`.

If i select iOS Distribution for content and service i got error.

[image: Image 2 Of Error]

What can i do for distribute my app?

Comment: You have to use same signin certificate for binary.this might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27908394/3514144)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fixed my issue by signing automatically. I was selected `Automatically manage signing`. Apple will manage signing certificates for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 12.4**. You can set it automatically. But I still got the error. I have added the Content and Service extension in my App target. So, for debugging purposes you need to register a new App ID(for Content extension and Service extension) on the developer account and also need to create two separate provisioning profiles. Set profile in both targets and run the App. While releasing the build where you set your app profile you also need to set profiles for Content extension and Service extension only then next button will become active.