# xcode 6.2 embedded binary is not signed with same certificate as the parent

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

now before you leave me with a link to another question, I will post some links I've visited which led me to dead end:

http://aplus.rs/2014/embedded-binary-is-not-signed-with-the-same-certificate-as-the-parent-app/

[Embedded Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467015/embedded-binary)

In my watchkit extension and watchkit app in build settings-code signing, all of them are listed as IOS Developer and I have tried switching it to my IphoneDeveloper account. I have tried removing all provisioning profiles from apple developer and finder so that xcode can reimport them. In my info plist files, the bundle id starts with the same id as the parent app. In the general tab for the watchkit app and extension the team is set to the same team as my parent app.

Sometimes when I change something, the general tab will show an icon and a fix issue button, but once its built I still get the same error. The app group in capabilities is turned on for each target.

I have no other ideas on what to do. If you have an idea please let me know.